# VBA excel Application.getsaveasfilename error 13

Tags: vba, excel

I'm trying to create a macro to have the user save a backup of the workbook to a specific place. I tried my code below but got an error 13 message. I don't need it to be saved as a macro-enabled workbook, but I thought that would be easier.

```
Sub openSaveDialog()
'
' gives error 13 message when clicking save
'
Dim saveSuccess As Boolean
Dim fNameRec As String
Dim dateNow As String
Dim saveToDir As String
saveToDir = "Z:\location of save\Old Archive spreadsheets\"
dateNow = Format(Now(), "mmddyyyy")
fNameRec = saveToDir & "BinderArchiveBackup_" & dateNow
Sheets(3).Range("E25") = fNameRec
'check if backed up today
If (Sheets(3).Range("E22") = Date) Then
    MsgBox "backup already saved today no need to save again"
    Exit Sub
End If

'open save as window
saveSuccess = Application.GetSaveAsFilename(InitialFileName:=fNameRec, FileFilter:= _
"Excel Files (*.xlsx)," & "*.xlsx, Macro Enabled" & _
"Workbook (*.xlsm), *xlsm")
'if backup saved, update date of last backup
If saveSuccess Then
    Sheets(3).Range "E22" = Date
    MsgBox "save successful"
End If
'if backup not saved, inform user
If Not saveSuccess Then
    MsgBox "save canceled, please save backup before adding new items to the archive today"
End If
End Sub
```

Things I tried tweaking

- File filter to just macro enabled
- File filter to just excel workbook
- Blank file filter saving as type all files
- Blank file filter with .xlsx at the end of the name
- initial filename without directory but with ChDir so it opens in the right save location anyway

Any help would be great.

---

Save as window that opens

[image: [1]]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`GetSaveAsFilename` returns a `Variant`, which will be a boolean `False` if the user cancelled the SaveAs dialog, or a string containing the filename that they chose if they didn't cancel the dialog.

Your line saying

```
Dim saveSuccess As Boolean
```

will cause an issue if a non-boolean value is returned.  So use

```
Dim saveSuccess As Variant
```

instead.

---

This will still leave you with other problems though:

1. `Sheets(3).Range "E22" = Date` is invalid, and is probably meant to be `Sheets(3).Range("E22") = Date`
2. `*xlsm` should probably be `*.xlsm`
3. At no point are you actually saving the file.  Your final bits of code should probably be something like:

   ```
   If saveSuccess = False Then
       'if backup not saved, inform user
       MsgBox "save canceled, please save backup before adding new items to the archive today"
   Else
       If UCase(Right(saveSuccess, 5)) = ".XLSM" Then
           ActiveWorkbook.SaveAs saveSuccess, xlOpenXMLWorkbookMacroEnabled
           'if backup saved, update date of last backup
           Sheets(3).Range("E22") = Date
           MsgBox "save successful"
       ElseIf UCase(Right(saveSuccess, 5)) = ".XLSX" Then
           ActiveWorkbook.SaveAs saveSuccess, xlOpenXMLWorkbook
           'if backup saved, update date of last backup
           Sheets(3).Range("E22") = Date
           MsgBox "save successful"
       Else
           MsgBox "Unrecognised file extension chosen - backup not created"
       End If
   End If
   ```

Comment: Thanks for the help. I found that my problem was with the formatting of the dateNow string. after putting in a MsgBox(dateNow) it showed that the string was listing the numbers with forward slashes separating months/days/years. when passed into the filename this caused the save as function to look for folders that didn't exist.

I replaced it with 
dateNow = month(Date) & day(Date) & year(Date)
and now it works

Comment: @NoNels That sounds really strange.  I had thought of invalid characters in the filename causing issues, so I tested what would happen with that, and all it did was blank the name out before displaying the dialog.  (And, despite the fact that it wouldn't give an error, I specifically checked your `dateNow` variable and ensured that you **weren't** putting forward slashes in it - you are using a `"mmddyyyy"` format that won't do so.)

Comment: You're right. I must have removed the quotation marks from `mmddyyyy` while I was fiddling with it yesterday after employing your fix. My bad. Tried using the code I posted and it acts like you described. I'm still fairly new to coding, and this was my first post, so I'm guessing it's my fault. the important thing is that the code works now. :)